# am i having whispers of shaytan?

Tags: waswasa

every since ramadan started i doubt if i broke my fast everyday because one day i did break my fast, and also when i pray i doubt if i’m doing it right because before i was saying fatiha wrong, and when i do any acts of worship i doubt if i’m pure because my phone became najis.

These problems are solved and i repented but i still get these doubts do i have whispers of shaytan if i do what can i do to rid them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to remember , not only through your prayers or your fast ; on your daily life Satan is there to put doubts in your heart . Make you feel inadequate,make you feel your sin is unforgivable. When your overtaken by this feeling open Quran and read verse after verse and page after page Allah proclaiming mercy and love and forgiveness. No sin is unforgivable as long as you repent and seek closeness to your maker .

Ramadan is not only a month to refrain from food and drink but improve yourself . Fight your shortcomings , your sins . Cure your soul with Quran and read and let it absorb to you . More it blends with you , less satans whispers will touch you. If you make a mistake , get up and don’t give up on the mercy of Allah

Answer (score 0):

Say istiatha.
Aaouthu billahi min elshaytan eljareem.
Allahuma inni south bike min waswasti elshayateen wa south bike Allahuma an yahdoroon.